# IIS 7 URL rewrite rules seem to be working one time only

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-7, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I am trying to force a website running under IIS to always run in https mode and redirect to it's full root name which includes www in order for the SSL certificate to work properly.

Below is the web.config entry:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^somewebsite.com$" ignoreCase="true"  />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

This works on first time requests, for instance someone requests: somewebsite.com in the browser URI for the very first time, they will be  automatically redirected to https://www.somewebsite.com. However, once the site is loaded and if user manually removes the www or https in the browser URI, the server does not perform subsequent redirects. Is that by design and is it possible for the rule to always execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use on all our live SSL sites. I use 2 rules and never had any problem with these:

```
<rule name="Redirect domain.com to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```